# ConnectionRequest issue

Tags: codenameone

I called 'new NewForm(res).show()' in postResponse but though the connection succeed, the particular form is not seen. I found out that if I comment out 'cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(d)', then it works fine.
But infinite progress runs infinitely if any exception occurs and so on. Is this a bug? It occured after I updated to new cn1 library update. If you want to see the project, its here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8LUdta0F5NXYzamM/view?usp=sharing

```
Button checkButton = new Button("Check");
checkButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    ConnectionCheck cc = new ConnectionCheck(theme);
    cc.connectionCheckMethod();
});
```

ConnectionCheck class

```
public class ConnectionCheck {

Resources res;
Dialog d;

public ConnectionCheck(Resources res) {
    this.res = res;
}

public void connectionCheckMethod() {
    ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jsonp = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parser = jsonp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            System.out.println("bibek " + parser);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
               new NewForm(res).show();
        //       d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
            System.out.println("login ErrorResponseCode " + code + "msg: " + message);
        //    d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
            System.out.println("login Exception " + err);
        //    d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
            System.out.println("login IOException " + err);
         //   d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException err) {
            System.out.println("login RuntimeException " + err);
        //    d.dispose();
        }
    };
    cr.setPost(true);
    cr.setUrl("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
    cr.setTimeout(30000);
    cr.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(d); //if this line is commented, the newForm is shown
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
    }
}
```

NewForm class

```
public class NewForm extends Form{

    public NewForm(Resources res){
        setTitle("new Form");
        add(new Label("new Form"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose the dialog before calling the show of the new form. Dispose on completion will dispose the dialog when the connection is done which is sometimes unpredictable.

When a dialog is disposed it returns to the previous form i.e. the one shown before the dialog was shown.

Comment: I've called new Form in postResponse method. PostResponse() should be called after connectionRequest succeeds (ie. dispose on completion is called before new Form in postResponse), isn't it? The above code used to work before. What changes should I do now? Do I have to dispose dialog box manually in post response method and each exception handle methods?